# Understanding assembly code: "mov dword" and "mov qword" in main.c

Tags: assembly

I have just converted this piece of code in assembly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return (1);
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Once you push the base-pointer value on to the stack, RSP will decrement automatically (to a lower address). This will also happen when memory was allocated for argc and argv ("mov dword" and "mov qword"). Is this correct? I don't see any instruction to move the stack-pointer up the stack, so I am assuming this is done implicitly.
2. The instruction "mov dword [rbp-4H], edi" is 4 bytes less than the address in RBP, this is as expected since DWORD is 4 bytes in length. What I am confused about is why "mov qword [rbp-10H], rsi" is 10H (16 bytes)? Isn't QWORD 8 bytes in length? I was expecting the instruction to be "mov qword [rbp-CH], rsi", since 4+8=12 bytes.
3. Can you explain to me what the comments on the right-side are?

Below is the assembly code generated from my c program:

```
SECTION .text   align=1 execute                         ; section number 1, code

main:   ; Function begin
push    rbp                                     ; 0000 _ 55
mov     rbp, rsp                                ; 0001 _ 48: 89. E5
mov     dword [rbp-4H], edi                     ; 0004 _ 89. 7D, FC
mov     qword [rbp-10H], rsi                    ; 0007 _ 48: 89. 75, F0
mov     eax, 1                                  ; 000B _ B8, 00000001
pop     rbp                                     ; 0010 _ 5D
ret                                             ; 0011 _ C3
; main End of function


SECTION .data   align=1 noexecute                       ; section number 2, data

SECTION .bss    align=1 noexecute                       ; section number 3, bss
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are aligned to some extent to help faster access to them. The alignment value is usually an implementation detail, but compilers usually follow Intel's recommendations to align/place variables next to each other.

According to [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf), section 3.6.7 Stack Alignment*:

> Performance penalty of unaligned access to the stack happens when a
> memory reference splits a cache line. This means that one out of eight
> spatially consecutive unaligned quadword accesses is always penalized,
> similarly for one out of 4 consecutive, non-aligned double-quadword
> accesses, etc.
>
> Aligning the stack may be beneficial any time there are
> data objects that exceed the default stack alignment of the system.
> For example, on 32/64bit Linux, and 64bit Windows, the default stack
> alignment is 16 bytes, while 32bit Windows is 4 bytes.
>
> ***Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 55. (H impact, M generality)** Make sure
> that the stack is aligned at the largest multi-byte granular data type
> boundary matching the register width.*

In your case on x64 the registers are 8 bytes wide and `argc` being an `int` is 4 bytes wide. Following the guideline above the variables are aligned to 8-byte boundary.

```
 ► 0x5555555545fe <main+4>                   mov    dword ptr [rbp - 4], edi
   0x555555554601 <main+7>                   mov    qword ptr [rbp - 0x10], rsi
   0x555555554605 <main+11>                  mov    eax, 0x2a
   0x55555555460a <main+16>                  pop    rbp
   0x55555555460b <main+17>                  ret
```

`edi` stores `argc` a 32 bit value - packed in a 64 bit boundary with the upper 32 bits of no use for you.

```
pwndbg> tele rbp-0x10
00:0000│          0x7fffffffdf10 —▸ 0x7fffffffe000 ◂— 0x1
01:0008│          0x7fffffffdf18 ◂— 0x0
02:0010│ rbp rsp  0x7fffffffdf20 —▸ 0x555555554610 (__libc_csu_init) ◂— push   r15
```

So the `argv` starts 8 bytes above `argv`